# x[0].html() or $(x)[0] is not a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 HTML DOM elements:

```
<div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">Universal Plug Adaptor</div>
<div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">WiFi Access</div>
<div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">LAN Cable</div>
<div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">Mouse</div>
```

I queried these DOM elements using jQuery:

```
var x = jQuery('div[data-equipment-type="addon"')
```

then I want to get the html() values of each DOM element store in x. Expected Output:

```
Universal Plug Adaptor
WiFi Access
LAN Cable
Mouse
```

However, the following functions does not work.

```
x[0].html()
$(x)[0].html()
```

but the following returns the html element:

```
x[0] //output is <div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">Universal Plug Adaptor </div>
$(x)[0] //output is <div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">Universal Plug Adaptor </div>
```

Comment: DOM elements and jQuery elements are not the same thing. DOM elements don't have a `.html()` method.

Comment: Your selector is wrong `jQuery('div[data-equipment-type="addon"]')`

Comment: Did you try `$(x[0]).html()`?

Comment: Based on your responses, it looks like I can either do it this way: (OPTION 1) $(x).eq(0).html() (OPTION 2) $(x)[0].innerHTML

Comment: HTML value as in `<div data-equipment-type="addon" style="display: inline-block;">Universal Plug Adaptor </div>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is now a jQuery collection (Array) of DOM elements.

```
x.eq(0).html()
```

or

```
$(x[0]).html()
```

or in JS

```
x[0].innerHTML
```

will get you the desired